# Applets are not running in my IE8 and firefox6.0.2

Tags: java, html, internet-explorer, firefox, applet

I have an Hello world applet,taken from book example.

**HelloWorldApplet.java**

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 * @version 1.22 2007-06-12
 * @author Cay Horstmann
 */
public class HelloWorldApplet extends JApplet
{
   public void init()
   {
      EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
         {
            public void run()
            {
               JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello, World applet", SwingConstants.CENTER);
               add(label);
            }
         });
   }
}
```

**HelloWorldApplet.html**

```
<html>
<body>
<applet code="HelloWorldApplet.class"
   width="300" height="100">
</applet>
</body>
</html>
```

and while running it in my browsers I have following trouble.

But other non-applet html files (say javascript files) are successfully displayed in both firefox and internet explorer.

**case FireFox version 6.0.2:**
   Firefox is abruptly getting closed whenever I execute this HelloWorldApplet.html in it.
Hence no output.

**case InternetExplorer version 8:**
  Internet exp. is showing "this tab has been recovered" whenever I execute this HelloWorldApplet.html in it. Hence no output.

**What I have done so far:**
   I tried out many links and followed their instructions.  But, In `Tools->Internet options->Advanced (tab) in internet explorer` and `Tools->Options in firefox` I cannot see any find any checkboxes releated to java as they said.
**Where the problem is:**
  They said if you cannot find any checkbox, then you must install JDK. But I already installed jdk 6.0.

In command-prompt,

```
C:\Users\MuthuGanapathy>java -version
java version "1.6.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_25-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)
```

which says java is installed in my system.

So, what I have to do now to run applets in my browers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deploying applets with the `applet` tag is deprecated. It still may work, and the behaviour you experienced is in any case not acceptable, but you still should try the current methods for (multi browser) applet deployment as outlined here first:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/applet/applet_deployment.html

Answer (score 0):

Check these settings

My Computer --> Control Panel

Here you should find an icon "Java"

Click on Java and go to "Advanced Tab"

Now in APPLET tag support, check boxes next to IE and Firefox.

Click OK and test again.

You can also enable Java Console ubder "Java Console" option and select radio button "Show Console".

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Really IE8 have some problems with Java. So here some instructions about how to set your IE8 to interact with JRE properly

> In IE 8 there is not a Java section on the advanced menu.  Java is
>   listed in the Add-ons.  To check if Java is installed and enabled
>   click on “Tools” on the IE Menu Bar and click Manage Add-ons.  In the
>   Manage Add-ons window make sure that Tool Bars and Extensions is
>   highlighted on the left hand side of the Window and then look for the
>   Sun Microsystems section in the main area of the window.  If it is
>   listed there but shows to be disabled, click on the Java plug-ins and
>   enable them.  If they do not show up in the Add-ins, it means that
>   Java didn’t install correctly.
>
> If Java was not installed correctly go to the Control Panel and
>   uninstall java.  Read this Microsoft Knowledge Base article about the
>   Windows Installer Cleanup Utility:
>
> http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;290301
>
> Download and install the utility.  Run it and look for the Java
>   install and remove the leftover install files if the utility finds
>   any.  Once this has been completed follow this link to download and
>   install Java 6:
>
> http://www.java.com/en/download/index.jsp

... so, as you can see, there can be two things either IE8 add-ons are not configured correctly or JRE wasn't installed correctly as it should be for OS...

Report that helps

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Check these settings

```
My Computer --> Control Panel
```

Here you should find an icon "Java"

Click on `Java` and go to `"General" -> "setting" -> "delete files..."`